# Find integer $x$ such that $x^2 \mod {1799832043}$ is divisible by $67610791$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Find integer $x$ such that $x^2 \mod {n}$ is divisible by $p$

For values $n = 1799832043, p = 67610791$

I have been using [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm) to solve this and it works for small primes with Legendre symbol $1$ like the number below

- $p=2,x=42425$
- $p=3,x=42425$
- $p=7,x=42430$
- $p=11,x=42430$
- $p=13, x=42429$

But for some reason, it's not working for $67610791$, why is that?

Comment: @Moo I am not really sure that I understand why are you asking, but you can assume that the answer is Yes.

Comment: @Moo Is there a tool that can reach infinite precision calculations ?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I found $$x=1555203848$$ but only by creating random numbers from $1$ to $1799832043$ until a solution was found.

Comment: That's cheating Peter! lol, It's definitely not the answer I am after.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I know, but that "double-modulo"-calculation is hard to handle. Maybe you show how your algorithm works for a small example. Perhaps this maeks it easier to find out why it fails for this example.

Comment: @Peter look at [ressol](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gazman/math/MathUtils.java)

Comment: Searching $k$ such that $k\cdot 1799832043+67610791$ is a perfect square gives a solution quickly here ($k=6$) , but I guess this also not what you want.

Comment: @Peter those are brute force solutions, they only good for small numbers.

Comment: Then, I have no idea, unfortunately. @Moo arbitary precision, yes. I was just confused because of the word "infinite" in this context.

Comment: See my answer below. The algorithm will also work for $p = 67610791$ but only if you take an $n$ for which $(\frac{n}{p})=+1$. for example $n=1799832042$.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an $x$ so that $x^2 \equiv n \mod p$. This implies that $(\frac{n}{p})=+1$.

As $n=28843 \cdot 62401$, this then implies that $(\frac{28843}{p})$ and $(\frac{62401}{p})$ both are $+1$, or both are $-1$.
But $(\frac{28843}{p}) =-1$ and $(\frac{62401}{p})=+1$.

This can be easily derived by applying the quadratic reciprocity law a number of times on both Legendre symbols, but can also be derived from the fact that when $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ (like $p=67610791$), then  $$[a^{\frac{p+1}{4}}]^2 = a^{\frac{p+1}{2}} = a \cdot a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv a \cdot (\frac{a}{p})$$
and calculate $28843^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$ and $62401^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$.

A relatively simple calculation shows that

$28843^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \equiv 275671$, and $275671^2 \equiv 67581948 \equiv -28843$

and

$62401^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \equiv 49327081$, and $49327081^2 \equiv 62401$

Hence 
$(\frac{n}{p})=(\frac{28843}{p}) \cdot (\frac{62401}{p})=-1$

If you like, you can also directly calculate $n^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$ of course:

$n^{\frac{p+1}{4}} \equiv 28238849$, and $28238849^2 \equiv -41951477 \equiv -n$